# Unreadable characters after echoing data from XML

Tags: php

Im retrieving data from XML

in XML it showing like this

```
Apartment Features • Balcony • Terrace • Outdoor Space • Dining Room • Dishwasher • Washer • Hardwood • High Ceilings • Renovated • Marble Bath • Granite Kitchen • Light • Laundry In Unit Building Specifics • Doorman • Elevator • Garage • Subway • Laundry
```

But if I echo it using PHP my page is showing it like this

```
Apartment Features� Balcony � Terrace� Outdoor Space� Dining Room�� Dishwasher� Washer� Hardwood� High Ceilings� Renovated�
```

How can I correctly display this?

Edit : My pages are using UTF-8. XML is showing actual bullets not something like `&bull;` or `<li>` but Im seen in a competitor website they can correctly display these. we are using the same XML Feed.

Comment: It will be an encoding issue. How are you reading the data from the XML file and how are you outputting it on the page? Simply outputting the string on blank page will display `Apartment Features� Balcony � Terrace�...` , but defining `<meta charset="utf-8">` will display them correctly.

Comment: Your edit didn't really explain anything further. How are you reading the data from your XML file? Are you immediately outputting the read content? Are you using some kind of encoding/decoding such as `utf8_encode()` or `utf8_decode()`? And how are your `pages are using UTF-8`?

Comment: Im reading it from XML as is then save it to DB then Im retrieving it from DB then output it to my page, My Page `<meta charset="utf-8">`. I also tried coping the XML text then paste it to my DB table, then retrieve it, still not showing the bullets

Comment: Is your DB server using `Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)`?

Comment: How would I know? By the way Im using MySQL on shared hosting

Comment: On the landing page of phpmyadmin It'll tell you your server charset, or you can run the query `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';` and it'll tell you.

Comment: It showing `Server charset:  UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)`

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple items that can affect the display of special characters. Most often it is due to trying to represent a non ASCII or multi-byte character with ASCII.  You can try to add the UTF-8 encoding into your header in the HTML/PHP page or ensure the data from the XML is the correct encoding.

Comment: My pages are using utf-8

Comment: if you run the XML variable from the result through htmlentities(), does it address the problem?

Comment: XML is showing actual bullets not something like `&bull;` or `<li>` but Im seen in a competitor website they can correctly display these. we are using the same XML Feed